# retrieve plaintext password from file using bash command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read a value from a known file.

File is located at /root/.my.cnf
and contains

```
[client]
password='PosftGlK2y'
```

I would like to return **PosftGlK2y** - ideally using a simple one liner command.

I have tried

```
cat /root/.my.cnf | grep password
```

which returns **password='PosftGlK2y'**

I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: You don't need to use `cat` -- `grep` could read the file.  That's call UUoC (Useless Use of `cat`).

Comment: To parse anything sophisticated enough, you probably don't want to reinvent the wheels but instead get a decent INI parser.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the `cat` and `grep` directly, and then pipe to `awk` with a `'` delimiter.

```
grep password /root/.my.cnf | awk -F"'" '{print $2}'
```

Alternately, you can skip the grep altogether and just use `awk` to do the search and the extraction.

```
awk -F"'" '/^password=/{print $2}' /root/.my.cnf
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Sure, I'll add that in.

Comment: `awk -F"'" ' /^password=/{print $2}' </root/.my.cnf`

Comment: And the selection might be better anchored to the start of the line and followed by an `=`, so you might have `awk '/^password=/ { ... }'`

Comment: ...of course, it's an issue if the file happens not to be written with single quotes.

Comment: This also will match any comments in the file containing the word "password", as currently written.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I"ll anchor it, but I am answering based on what the OP has provided, rather than making inferences about what else is in the file.

Comment: @merlin2011, pardon? Being restrictive, to only match what the OP *showed in the question* was in the file, is the safe approach; matching other possible content, by contrast, violates Postel's Law (the "liberal in what you accept" part, particularly), as it means you're potentially behaving in unexpected/buggy ways when faced with unspecified contents.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut` to split the line on the `'` character:

```
grep password= /root/.my.cnf | cut -d "'" -f 2
```

returns

```
PosftGlK2y
```

The cut command splits a line on the delimiter (`-d` flag) and returns the column(s) specified by the `f` flag.